# Am I getting the principal value of angle from sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, equation

Here's part of my code in solving two equations:

```
delta, beta = symbols('delta, beta')    #Two unknowns are delta and beta.
eq1 = Eq((tan((delta+beta)/2)),nz*tan(theta/2))
eq2 = Eq((tan((delta-beta)/2)),nx/ny)
result = solve((eq1, eq2), (delta, beta))
print(result)
```

Plugging in all the known values, I got `{delta: 0.148665671805423, beta: 0.124084722157366}`.
However, since delta and beta have infinitely many values (with period 2*pi). I'm wondering am I only getting the principal value here (the possible value range from -pi to pi)? In other words, why there are no infinitely many solutions appear here? Thanks!!

Comment: Are you asking if 0.14 and 0.12 are between -pi and pi?

Comment: @kaya3 No, I'm wondering if my guess is correct. (why am I getting 0.148 instead of 0.148+2*n*pi)

Comment: It's still not clear what you actually want an answer to - you can see that your code gives that result, and you can see that the result is the principal values of the angles.

Comment: @kaya3 Is it a convention that only principal values are returned?

Comment: The `solve` function only returns principal values. The `solveset` function returns full infinite sets of solutions (but only handles univariate equations).

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin Thanks so much:)